# Wrong exponential sampling in PyMC

Tags: python, pymc

I'am obviously doing something wrong here... Please have a look at the following program. It runs well but gives me a `lambda` parameter for an exponential distribution which is far away from the parameter I used for generating random observations:

```
import numpy as np
import arviz as az
import pymc as pm

lambda_param = 0.25
random_size = 1000
x = np.random.exponential(lambda_param, random_size)

basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:
    _lam_ = pm.HalfNormal("lambda", sigma = 1)
    Y_obs = pm.Exponential("Y_obs", lam = _lam_, observed = x)
    start = pm.find_MAP(model = basic_model)
    idata = pm.sample(1000, start = start)

summary = az.summary(idata, round_to = 6)
summary
```

Following my last running of the program, I find in summary a `mean lambda` greater than `4`..., where `lambda=0.25` as I used it.

Pointing the finger at my programing errors would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the large uncertainty on lambda is messing with your result, did you try `_lam_ = pm.HalfNormal("lambda", sigma = 0.01)`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the uncertainty on `_lam_` was too large and given that the exponential probability distribution is not symmetric, the high uncertainty modified the result. The fix is simply to use a smaller standard deviation, I also used `Normal` rather than `HalfNormal` for simplicity:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz as az

lambda_param = 0.25
random_size = 1000
x = np.random.exponential(lambda_param, random_size)

with pm.Model() as basic_model:
    lam = pm.Normal("lam", mu=lambda_param, sigma=0.0001)
    Y_obs = pm.Exponential("Y_obs", lam=lam, observed=x)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
    
summary = az.summary(trace, round_to=6)
summary
```

This gives a mean of `0.25` for lambda, within a small margin of error.

Comment: Note : I used `import pymc as pm`, not `pycm3`…
Then, following your recommendations :
• `pm.HalfNormal("lambda", sigma = 0.0001)` gives me `lambda = 0.003…`
• `pm.HalfNormal("lambda", sigma = 1)` gives me `lambda = 3.86…`
• `pm.Normal("lam", mu=lambda_param, sigma=0.0001)` gives me `lambda = 0.25`
• `pm.Normal("lam", mu=lambda_param, sigma=1)` gives me `lambda = 3.99…`

Comment: The problem (to me) is : having data roughly exponentially distributed with no previous idea about the parameter `lambda`, why should I have chosen `pm.Normal()` instead of  `pm.HalfNormal()` ? As `lambda > 0`, `pm.HalfNormal()` automatically seems like the best choice, isn’t it ?
And then, why should I have chosen a so small `sigma`?
This kind of modeling looks like a stroke of luck, right ?

Comment: @Andrew good points, I never used this package for monte carlo simulation so maybe I got lucky